# type Parameter name: Type is not derived from a java type. - Xamarin android

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

My app was working fine. All of a sudden I realized I am getting this error when I try to sign in and sign out using Facebook. In my app, when i sign in through Faceboook, it authenticates fine from the Facebook login page to a success page page.

On the success page, the user clicks on continue, When I click on the continue, I get the error

> type Parameter name: Type is not derived from a java type.

The app crashes and restarts, after i see that the user has been logged in.
When I logout too, it get the same error

> type Parameter name: Type is not derived from a java type.

The app crashes but the user is logged out.  I have searched other questions related but none could help me.

What is causing this?

```
 public class successPage : Activity

    {
        Button button;
        TextView textViewActivity;
        FirebaseAuth mAuth;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);


            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.successPage);

            button = (Button)FindViewById(Resource.Id.button);

            textViewActivity = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.textView);

            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.Instance;



            button.Click += onBtnClick;

            //textViewActivity.Text = user.DisplayName;



            // Create your application here
        }

        private void onBtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Intent success = new Intent(this, (typeof(EventNews)));
            StartActivity(success);
        }
    }
```

The error points at this line

```
Intent success = new Intent(this, (typeof(EventNews)));
```

**EventNews**

```
public class EventNews : BaseActivity, IValueEventListener
    {

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);


            FrameLayout content = (FrameLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.content_frame);
            LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.EventNews, content);



            //initializing firebase
            user = FirebaseAuth.Instance.CurrentUser;


            toolbarMain = (Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar)FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolBar);

            SetSupportActionBar(toolbarMain);

            TextView toolbarName = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.counter_text);

        }

        }

        public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
        {

            MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.top_menus, menu);

            var item = menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.search);

            var searchview = (Android.Support.V7.Widget.SearchView)MenuItemCompat.GetActionView(item);

            searchview.QueryTextChange += (s, e) =>
            {

                adapter.Filter.InvokeFilter(e.NewText);



            };

            searchview.QueryTextSubmit += (s, e) =>

            {

                Toast.MakeText(this, "Searched for: " + e.Query, ToastLength.Short).Show();
                e.Handled = true;
            };

            MenuItemCompat.SetOnActionExpandListener(item, new SearchViewExpandListener(adapter));




            return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        }

        private void Adapter_ItemClick(object sender, int position)
        {


        }

        private class SearchViewExpandListener : Java.Lang.Object, MenuItemCompat.IOnActionExpandListener
        {
            private readonly IFilterable _adapter;

            public SearchViewExpandListener(IFilterable adapter)
            {
                _adapter = adapter;

            }
            public bool OnMenuItemActionCollapse(IMenuItem item)
            {
                _adapter.Filter.InvokeFilter("");
                return true;
            }

            public bool OnMenuItemActionExpand(IMenuItem item)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        public void OnCancelled(DatabaseError error)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void OnDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot)
        {

            eventNews.Clear();
            var items = snapshot.Children.ToEnumerable<DataSnapshot>();

            HashMap map;
            foreach (DataSnapshot item in items)
            {
                map = (HashMap)item.Value;

                eventNews.Add(new EventNews(item.Key.ToString(),map.Get("Name")?.ToString(), map.Get("Achievement")?.ToString(),map.Get("History")?.ToString(),map.Get("Quote")?.ToString(), map.Get("Ref").ToString()));
            }

            //list items on listview
            rv.SetLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            rv.SetItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
            rv.SetAdapter(adapter);
            mDialog.Dismiss();


        }
    }
```

**StackTrace**

```
  at Java.Lang.Class.FromType (System.Type type) [0x00012] in <d855bac285f44dda8a0d8510b679b1e2>:0 
  at Android.Content.Intent..ctor (Android.Content.Context packageContext, System.Type type) [0x00000] in <d855bac285f44dda8a0d8510b679b1e2>:0 
  at peaceApp.Droid.successPage.onBtnClick (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e) [0x00002] in /Users/emmnock/Documents/Projects/peaceApp/Droid/successPage.cs:76 
  at Android.Views.View+IOnClickListenerImplementor.OnClick (Android.Views.View v) [0x00011] in <d855bac285f44dda8a0d8510b679b1e2>:0 
  at Android.Views.View+IOnClickListenerInvoker.n_OnClick_Landroid_view_View_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_v) [0x0000f] in <d855bac285f44dda8a0d8510b679b1e2>:0 
  at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:579ed970-959a-4157-8d2c-b00f36f55fa7 (intptr,intptr,intptr)
```

Comment: The error points at this line `Intent success = new Intent(this, (typeof(EventNews)));`

Comment: Can you add what the `EventNews` is?

Comment: The second parameter expects a class i think, not a Type.

Comment: I have added the EventNews Class please

Comment: @Switz try to inherit the `EventNews` from `Android.App.Activity` instead of `BaseActivity`.

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov, i had an activity called MainActivity (which was been used in the success page at first) inheriting from BaseActivity and it worked fine and recently changed to EventNews and it was working fine. Just realized yesterday that this error was coming up

Comment: @Switz can you add the full exception with stacktrace?

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov stack trace added please

Comment: @Switz are other Activities implementing this `IValueEventListener` interface? The problem is that your `typeof(EventNews)` is getting into this if statement `if (!(typeof (IJavaObject).IsAssignableFrom (type)))` where the exception is being thrown

Comment: Yes all my activities are implementing IValueEventListener except my MainActivity.  I don't understand this `if (!(typeof (IJavaObject).IsAssignableFrom (type)))`

Comment: @Switz this checks if the Type that you have passed is valid for IJavaObject to be assigned from.

Comment: Okay I get it now. But then since almost all my activities implement IValueEventListener, how do i go about that?

Comment: @Switz I don't think that the IValueEventListener is the reason, because then all your other Activities also won't work

Comment: @Switz can you try to inherit `BaseActivity` from `Android.App.Activity` instead of `AppCompatActivity`?

Comment: It is still the same. But my problem is when i change EventNews to MainActivity(which also inheriting BaseActivity) it works fine.

Comment: @Switz is this mistake while copy pasting code to here in your `EventNews` source or this is really so?          `TextView toolbarName = (TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.counter_text);

        }

        }` double closing `}`?

Comment: Copy and paste error. It wouldn't have built in the first place if there was an error in the EventNews Class :)

Comment: @Switz here is what `IsAssignableFrom ` checking http://take.ms/Rycd6 I can't figure out why are you getting this exception. The only idea is that for some reason it's not being bonded correctly to the `Java`'s activity

Comment: Alright.. I will look up with other solutions anyway

Comment: i found it... a silly error  i made.. My type and activity naming conventions have almost similar names

Comment: @Switz so you were passing not your Type?

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov yeah exactly

Comment: @Switz that's funny, but this question gave me opportunity to look into the source of xamarin-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have checked this documentation [Passing Data Between Activities](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/fundamentals/activity/pass_data_between_activity/)

Then you may be have noticed this line:

> Add a second activity class named Activity2 to the project. **This class must inherit from Android.App.Activity**.

So the problem is in `typeof(EventNews)`. For some reason as a type is being passed not the type of your activity. This may be if you have two classes with the same name but in different namespaces.

Comment: I don't really get this anyway. Because i have about 4 other activities in my app inheriting BaseActivity and i am able to pass data between Activities. Base Activity is inheriting from AppCompatActivity. That is where i set my Nav drawer and toolbar.